# How to replace values in ini file using sed?

Tags: sed

This example is from devstack script.

```
sed -i -e "/^\[$section\]/,/^\[.*\]/ s|^\($option[ \t]*=[ \t]*\).*$|\1$value|" "$file"
```

Can anyone explain how this `sed` replace command works?

I understand some basic `sed` machanism, but this seems to be complicated for me.

Comment: But isn't the grouping and/or replacement wrong!? `key=oldValue` will be replaced with `key=oldValueNewValue`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The -i option edits the file $file in place.

## Address Range

The syntax for a range of lines to match is /pattern1/,/pattern2/
The script searches for the range of lines from the first line containing a character in $section at the beginning of the line (note use of caret) to this ^[.*] which denotes a line which contains at least one character.

## Substitution

For all lines which match the range specifier above, a substitute command s/pattern/replacement/ command is performed.
Note the use of | to delimit the substitute command - s|pattern|replacement|.

The pattern to match uses caret (^) starts at the beginning of the line.

The section (....) is in the replacement section referred to as \1.

In the (...) section is the string $section followed by possibly a number of space or tab characters - [ \t]* represents none or more tabs or spaces. Followed by a '=' char, possibly more spaces or tabs. The .*$ will match any number of chars to the end of the line.

The replacement \1$value is the section contained (...) as mentioned before, followed by the value in $value.

HTH!